Rav Soloveitchik on Chanukah and the Hellenists
In the book "The Light and the Splendor: The Radiance and Inspiration of the Days of Triumph and Gratitude" by Rav Daniel Glatstein shlita (p. 218), he quotes from Rav Soloveitchik and says that when we read in Al HaNisim:"וְאַחַר כֵּן בָּאוּ בָנֶיךָ" (Your children came to the Holy of Holies of Your house) means that:

Hashem's children, the Jews, came back to observance after having accepted the culture and beliefs of the Yevanim! These Misyavnim returned to a life of kedushah, Torah and mitzvos. After abandoning the faith of their ancestors, the wayward Jews repented and returned to Torah observance.


[...] The real story of Chanukah was that the majority of Klal Yisrael left Yiddishkeit, abandoned mitzvos, and became Misyavnim.

Does anyone know where Rav Soloveitchik said this in the journal הדרום and if this can be found online?

It's HaDarom ("the south") -- https://www.jta.org/2007/03/13/default/torah-journal-goes-online

@Shalom Wonderful. Did not know about the journal. Are you maybe able to find the specific location?

There are a few items here in HaDarom but none look promising https://traditiononline.org/ravbiblio/ Is that an exact quoation?

@DoubleAA Thanks, but I could not find anything. It must be online, since others have it :)

Did you try contacting the author? https://www.rabbidg.com/contact

@DoubleAA Nope, I wanted to first find out myself!

This can be found in a collection of the Rav's lectures and writings, edited by R. Schechter, called MePeninei Harav. On page 145, the original of what you quoted in translation (and interpretation) appears:

המלים בתפילת על הנסים ״כשעמדה מלכות יון הרשעה״ אינן מכוונים ליוונים הגויים, אלא ליהודים המתיוונים שבעטו בדתם. זאת הפעם הראשונה, וגם האחרונה, שרוב היהודים המירו את דתם. אמנם היו קבוצות קטנות או כתות אחדות שהמירו את דתן, אבל שוב לא היתה קהילה שלימה שהמירו את דתה כמו שאירע בימים ההם. תפקיד החשמונאים היה לחדש את האמונה בלב העם, להעלותו מעומק הטומאה, ולהדריכו למעלות הטהרה, כדי שלא יתרחש שוב מקרה כזה. ולכן רוב ההלכות מי״ח הגזירות נתקנו קרוב לנצחון זה


Yeeees, wonderful! Thank you very much! Chanukah Sameach! :)

A well-earned bag of 400 pts-gelt just in time for Chanukah.

Absolutely, problem is I can’t click on the award button for at least a day :( but totally earned ;) chanukah sameach to you all!
